# Помогите разобрать пример на Rust

Tags: rust

Код взят из перевода The Rust Programming Language, [раздел Шаблоны](http://kgv.github.io/rust_book_ru/src/patterns.html#%D0%A1%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5).

```
struct Person {
    name: Option<String>,
}
let name = "Steve".to_string();
let mut x: Option<Person> = Some(Person { name: Some(name) });
match x {
    Some(Person { name: ref a @ Some(_), .. }) => println!("{:?}", a),
    _ => {}
}
```

Я не пойму откуда взялся `Some` и что это вообще такое. Возможно я что-то пропустил и теперь не понимаю. Объясните что это и какая полезность такой конструкции в этом код. Person структура, но зачем мы помещаем его в Some какой-то..

Comment: [_Type Option represents an optional value: every Option is either Some and contains a value, or None, and does not._](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/), Переводится примерно так: Тип _Option_ представляет опциональное значение: если _Some_ - то содержится значение, если _None_ - нет

Answer (score 2):

Some - это конструктор типа `Option`. Мы используем его в сопоставлении с образцом (`match`). Если в `x` находится `Some`, выполнится ветвь `println!("{:?}", a),`. Это похоже на `switch`, но выбор варианта производится не по числовому значению, а по тому, находится в `Option` - `Some<T>` или `None`.

Структуру мы помещаем в `Some` чтобы указать, что структура может отсутствовать. Поскольку в Rust структуры хранятся по значению, как только значение типа `Person` объявлено и проинициализировано, оно гарантированно существует. `Option<Person>` указывает, что `Person` может быть, а может и не быть.

Answer (score 2):

Отвечаю на вопрос «откуда взялся Some». Тип Option объявлен так:

```
enum Option<T> {
  Some(T),
  None,
}
```

То есть обозначает nulllable тип (может быть, а может и нет), типобезопасная замена NULL. NULL в Си может заменить любой тип, так что при его передаче оригинальный тип теряется, а None всегда связан с каким-то оригинальным типом.

В безопасном коде в Расте NULL передать нельзя, поэтому если какой-то параметр или переменная может отсутствовать, то этот факт объявляется компилятору явно через тип Option.

В обычной ситуации обращение к вариантам enum идёт с квалификацией, то есть можно написать так: `Option::Some(T)`, `Option::None`. Однако тип Option настолько часто используется, что в стандартной прелюдии std::prelude делается `use Option::*;`, что делает варианты этого типа Some и None доступными без полной квалификации.

Comment: Ещё один enum-тип, варианты которого заимпортированы в прелюдии `enum Result<T, E> { Ok(T), Err(E), }` (используется в ситуациях, когда нужно вернуть или значение, или ошибку, идеологически заменяет исключения), поэтому везде пишут просто Ok и Err вместо Result::Ok и Result::Err. Если хотите к вариантам своего enum-а обращаться напрямую, можете тоже сделать `use MyEnum::*;`, но это не рекомендуется, т.к. засоряет пространство имён. Result и Option на особом положении, т.к. фактически системные и используются везде.